# Select From a list of layers to overlay on google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, overlay, gwt-openlayers

Can anyone advise me on how to select layers from a checkbox overlay the selected layer on google maps?

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript Version:**

Please consult the Google Maps API documentation.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#TrafficLayer

Here's a good example of adding and removing overlays.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-remove

**Java Version:**

Here's a nice example for Java. It even has a radio box to switch between layers.

http://demo.gwt-openlayers.org/gwt_ol_showcase/GwtOpenLayersShowcase.html?example=Basic%20Google%20V3%20example

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear to me.

Like in the previous answer : this is an example on how to use google v3 --> http://demo.gwt-openlayers.org/gwt_ol_showcase/GwtOpenLayersShowcase.html?example=Basic%20Google%20V3%20example

Overlay layers can be realized using setIsBaseLayer(false) method.
Base layers are drawn add the bottom, and can be switched using a radio button.
Overlay layers are drawn on top of the base layer, and can be switched using checkboxes (and thus multiple overlay layers can be enabled at once).

Or are you reffering to the specific google overlays (like traffic layer) ?